# Ajax Control Tooolkit menuPopupextender con Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ajax

Necesito colocar una ventana popup en una aplicación Asp Net con Visual Studio 2015. para ello utilicé el MeúPopUp Extender de Ajax Control Toolkit (versión 16.1.0) hice el ejemplo más básico, pero no resulta.
he buscado y leído, pero todos los ejemplos y comentarios siempre hablan de Ajax Toolkit con las versiones 2010, 2013 .
¿a caso no funciona con la versión 2315?
quedo atento a sus comentarios
saludos

Comment: pero no funciona por algun error ? si es asi deberias mencionar que dice el exception. O simplemente no muestra el popup, si es asi validaste desde el Developer Tools del browser si hay un error en javascript

Comment: simplemente no ejecuta nada... lo probé con Crome y Firefox y funciona pero con la versión de iExplorer 11 no hace absolutamente nada. también revise la vista de compatibilidad pero nada.. es como si al presionar el botón no hiciera nada.